# PhoneGap Android - Invalid keystore format generated under Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, phonegap-build, keytool

PhoneGap send me this error :

> Error - Invalid keystore format - You can fix this here

Here is the command I do to generate it (in Ubuntu) :

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore ToZer0.keystore -alias ToZer0 -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

I have no idea why it doesn't work !

Comment: [Ubuntu Phone and Tablet](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=460)  on ubuntuforums

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just forget the keysize I think...

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore tozer0.keystore -alias tozer0 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000